# C++ Почему нельзя хранить адрес переменной в обычной переменой типа int, а нужно писать int*?

Tags: c++, c, указатели, адрес

Зачем класть адрес переменной, например int, в определенный тип int*, если можно класть адрес в обычную переменную int, предположим, что разрядность процессора точно такая же как и у типа int? В чем проблема?

Comment: Внутри все так и есть.

Comment: Арифметика указателей зависит от типа, на адрес которого держит указатель, или вы хотите каждый раз писать `ptr + sizeof(int)`? Также по типу определяется, сколько именно байт занимает объект, на который указывает указатель.

Comment: Кроме того, когда вы по этому указателю захотите взять значение, (x=*var) компилятор должен будет знать, сколько байт по этому адресу надо брать. Тип указателя как раз это подсказывает компилятору

Answer (score 15):

Во-первых, в терминологии языков C и C++ термин "адрес" является синонимом термина "указатель" (или "значение типа указатель").

Во-вторых, языки С и С++ являются *строго типизированными* языками. В переменную типа "целое число" нельзя просто так взять и неявно записать значение типа "указатель". Это нарушение правил типизации языков С и С++. (Если вы не понимаете, в чем заключается цель и ценность строгой типизации, то это отдельный широкий вопрос.)

В-третьих, сам ваш вопрос построен на некорректной посылке. Кто вам сказал, что этого делать нельзя? Никто вам не запрещает в С и С++ сохранить значение указателя `int *` в переменной типа `int`, если ширина типа `int` достаточна для этого. Просто для этого требуется *явное* приведение типа

```
int a = 0;
int p = (int) &a;
```

В стандартной библиотеке этих языков есть даже специально заведенные целочисленные типы `intptr_t`/`uintptr_t`, которые как раз и предназначены именно для этого, т.е. для хранения приведенных к целому типу значений указателей.

Разумеется, для того, чтобы снова использовать такое сохраненное значение в роли указателя, вам придется сначала явно привести его обратно к типу "указатель".

---

В далекие 70-е годы, когда язык С еще только зарождался (см. [C Reference Manual](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/cman.pdf)), он допускал определенные варианты смешанного использования целых типов и указателей. В частности, в левой части оператора `->` можно было указывать целочисленные значения

```
struct S {
  int s_a; /* смещение 0 */
  int s_b; /* смещение 2 */
};

/* "С Reference Manual" явным образом утверждал, 
   что тип `int` имеет размер именно в 2 байта */

...
int a = 0x1234;
a->s_b = 42; /* записываем 42 в int по адресу 0x1236 */
...
```

Но от таких трюков быстро отказались.

Comment: `int s_a` оно 16-битное в 16-битной версии с++, лучше записать `short s_a` или `int16 s_a`. Думаю, что большинство людей уже видет в int 32 бита. Сейчас будет рабочим код (при отключеной оптимизации) `S* a; (int)a = 0x1234; a->s_b = 42;`

Comment: @nick_n_a: "С Reference Manual", на который я сослался, открытым текстом постулировал, что тип `int` имеет размер именно в 2 байта.

Comment: Спасибо, мануал и правда врядли будут читать.

Comment: @nick_n_a: `(int)a = 0x1234` ни в коем случае "рабочим не будет". Это дикое расширение GCC уже давно вымели из GCC поганой метлой и забыли как страшный сон. Результат преобразования типа в языке С некогда не является lvalue и в левой части оператора присваивания присутствовать не может.

Comment: Borland C++ такие махинации позволял делать в т ч Builder 5-версия. VS2005 уже нет. Ну тогда хотя бы так `((S*)a)->s_b;` ну уж сильно сказачно выглядит код, неужели есть компиляторы которые такое соберут...

Comment: @nick_n_a: Язык С, который описан в старинном "C Reference Manual" - это язык, в котором оператор `+=` записывался как `=+`, поля структур являлись *глобальными* идентификаторами смещения, переменные инициализировались как `int a 42;` (просто пробел вместо `=`), метки были *переменными* типа `int *` и т.п. Это был сильно другой язык, в котором было много "сказочного". Наш привычный C начал формироваться с K&R. А это то, что было до K&R. Компиляторов того С, я думаю, уже давно нет. А если и есть, то не на "наших" платформах.

Comment: Насчет строгой типизации вы погорячились: Си относится к слабо типизированным языкам.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov: Не вижу причин для такого заявления. Почему "слабо"? Не говоря уже о том, что разница в строгости типизации между С и С++ сводится фактически только к преобразованиям из `void *` и к преобразованиям `int` к `enum`.

Answer (score 4):

Можно хранить. Просто покажу свой код.

```
unsigned long long & __getWrapper(){
    static unsigned long long address = 0u; // здесь и хранится адрес
    return address;
}

Wrapper* getWrapper(){
        return (Wrapper*)__getWrapper();
}

void setWrapper( Wrapper * wrapper ){
    __getWrapper() = (unsigned long long)((void*)wrapper);
}

void f(){
     Wrapper * wrapper = getWrapper();
     wrapper->что-то там...
}

int main(){
    Wrapper* wrapper = new Wrapper;
    setWrapper( wrapper );
    f();
    return 0;
}
```